# Why OpenGL's anti-alias didn't work?

Tags: opengl

I've been studying how to use anti-alias in OpenGL. [Here](http://glprogramming.com/red/chapter06.html#name2) is a tutorial I found.

The Example 6-5 is a small program that is supposed to demonstrate the anti-alias for polygons.

```
#include <GL/gl.h>
#include <GL/glu.h>
#include <GL/glut.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

GLboolean polySmooth = GL_TRUE;
static void init(void)
{
    glCullFace(GL_BACK);
    glEnable(GL_CULL_FACE);
    glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA_SATURATE, GL_ONE);
    glClearColor(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0);
}

#define NFACE 6
#define NVERT 8
void drawCube(GLdouble x0, GLdouble x1, GLdouble y0,
              GLdouble y1, GLdouble z0, GLdouble z1)
{
    static GLfloat v[8][3];
    static GLfloat c[8][4] = {
        {0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0}, {1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0},
        {0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0}, {1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0},
        {0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0}, {1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0},
        {0.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0}, {1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0}
    };

/*  indices of front, top, left, bottom, right, back faces  */
    static GLubyte indices[NFACE][4] = {
        {4, 5, 6, 7}, {2, 3, 7, 6}, {0, 4, 7, 3},
        {0, 1, 5, 4}, {1, 5, 6, 2}, {0, 3, 2, 1}
    };

    v[0][0] = v[3][0] = v[4][0] = v[7][0] = x0;
    v[1][0] = v[2][0] = v[5][0] = v[6][0] = x1;
    v[0][1] = v[1][1] = v[4][1] = v[5][1] = y0;
    v[2][1] = v[3][1] = v[6][1] = v[7][1] = y1;
    v[0][2] = v[1][2] = v[2][2] = v[3][2] = z0;
    v[4][2] = v[5][2] = v[6][2] = v[7][2] = z1;

#ifdef GL_VERSION_1_1
    glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
    glEnableClientState(GL_COLOR_ARRAY);
    glVertexPointer(3, GL_FLOAT, 0, v);
    glColorPointer(4, GL_FLOAT, 0, c);
    glDrawElements(GL_QUADS, NFACE * 4, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, indices);
    glDisableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
    glDisableClientState(GL_COLOR_ARRAY);
#else
    printf("If this is GL Version 1.0, ");
    printf("vertex arrays are not supported.\n");
    exit(1);
#endif
}

/*  Note:  polygons must be drawn from front to back
 *  for proper blending.
 */
void display(void)
{
    if (polySmooth)
    {
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
        glEnable(GL_BLEND);
        glEnable(GL_POLYGON_SMOOTH);
        glDisable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
    }
    else
    {
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
        glDisable(GL_BLEND);
        glDisable(GL_POLYGON_SMOOTH);
        glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
    }

    glPushMatrix();
    glTranslatef(0.0, 0.0, -8.0);
    glRotatef(30.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0);
    glRotatef(60.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0);
    drawCube(-0.5, 0.5, -0.5, 0.5, -0.5, 0.5);
    glPopMatrix();

    glFlush();
}

void reshape(int w, int h)
{
    glViewport(0, 0, (GLsizei) w, (GLsizei) h);
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();
    gluPerspective(30.0, (GLfloat) w / (GLfloat) h, 1.0, 20.0);
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    glLoadIdentity();
}

void keyboard(unsigned char key, int x, int y)
{
    switch (key)
    {
    case 't':
    case 'T':
        polySmooth = !polySmooth;
        glutPostRedisplay();
        break;
    case 27:
        exit(0);        /*  Escape key  */
        break;
    default:
        break;
    }
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    glutInit(&argc, argv);
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_SINGLE | GLUT_RGB | GLUT_ALPHA | GLUT_DEPTH);
    glutInitWindowSize(200, 200);
    glutCreateWindow(argv[0]);
    init();
    glutReshapeFunc(reshape);
    glutKeyboardFunc(keyboard);
    glutDisplayFunc(display);
    glutMainLoop();
    return 0;
}
```

I copied the code to my computer (Ubuntu 11), compiled it and get this:

[image]

Reading the code, I think when press the `t` button, the polygons are supposed to be anti-aliased. And this picture is taken after I pressed the `t` button. As far as I can see, I don't think these are anti-aliased polygons, is there something wrong in what I did?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

POLYGON_SMOOTH is useless (don't trusk the red book ^^ ). Most graphic cards don't implement that.

Simply add "| GLUT_MULTISAMPLE" in glutInitDisplayMode(). This will add full-screen (well, full-window) antialiasing with the MSAA technique ( Multi Sampled AA ). If it doesn't work, try with freeglut. You can find opengl samples here : [OpenGL Samples Pack](http://www.g-truc.net/project-0026.html#menu) , they use freeglut.

Comment: I have searched for this problem the whole moring until I see your answer--just try freeglut.thanks man!